# Skip reporting a TestNG test based on conditions of the test

Tags: java, groovy, testng

Is it possible to not report tests based on conditions of the test. Could this be done in the test, changing test name, then exclude it during the report? Or is there another test framework that could do this?

For example if condition or exceptions X occurs then the test would not be in the XML reports.

I am trying this with Groovy/Java.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions : 
1) You can skip the test from getting executed by using SkipExecution exception of testNG. it will show as yellow in your report notifying that the test was skipped and then you can show some user message.
2) You can implement IMethodInterceptor if you know before hand that this test are not suppose to be run. you can write down some logic to exclude those test at run time from getting executed.